# Asp.Net adds wraps buttons with <I></I>?

Tags: asp.net

I am updating my current project with a new theme. For some reason, Asp.Net adds  tags around my buttons when they render? I have never experienced this before.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

[image]

Comment: I do not think aspnet is doing that. The I tag means Italic letter type. Remove the theme and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be caused by a JS library that added wave effects to the buttons. Turning off the effect  fixed it.